# Website show "Welcome to nginx!" as home index Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, ubuntu-18.04, puma

My rails web application show as homepage "Welcome to nginx!".
I have tried someones tips, but not work for me.
I dont have a .com domain DNS, so i access with IP address.
When i access http://myip, a get a "Welcome to nginx!",
but if i access http://myip/model, so i get a right rails application website

Im on Ubuntu 18.04,
Puma 3.12.1,
Nginx 1.14,
Rails 5.2.3,
Ruby 2.5.1

"/etc/nginx/sites-available/default"

```
upstream app {
    server unix:/home/benhur/servidor/shared/sockets/puma.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my_ip

    root /home/benhur/servidor/public;

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

    location @app {
        proxy_pass http://app;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
```

"/etc/nginx/nginx.conf"

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
}

http {
        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        gzip on;

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

What configuration i have to do for nginx show right rails application in all pages for my web application, include homepage.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: So, i found a solution, sorry for wasting yours time. For the record i delete a line "server_name my_ip"

Comment: The problem was a missing `;` at the end of the `server_name` line that caused the `root` statement to be ignored.

Comment: y'are completely right, im so dumb.